# Deleting a data using ID in database using rest controller, controller through a form in jsp - spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, controller, spring-restcontroller

I am performing a delete operation using spring boot @RestController and @Controller to handle it and send it to the view JSP page. I get an error that the id is null. I dont understand it and I tried few steps based on searches but was not helpful.

**@RestController is as follows:**

```
    @DeleteMapping(path = "shoelist/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ShoeData data = shoeService.deleteById(id);
        
        if(data != null) {
            // noContent means it would return 204 status code 
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
```

**@Controller is as follows:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "deletebyid", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteById( Long id) {
        ResponseEntity data = resource.delete(id);
        return "redirect:entry";
    }
```

**JSP page is as follows:**

```
    <h3>To delete an Item:</h3>
    <form action="deletebyid" method="get">
        Enter Shoe name: <input type="text" name="shoename"><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**error stack trace is:**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because "id" is null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because "id" is null
> at com.sportyshoes.basepackage.resource.RestfulResource.delete(RestfulResource.java:55)
> at com.sportyshoes.basepackage.controller.WareHouseController.deleteById(WareHouseController.java:85)

**and also in the URL it is showing the below:**

> http://localhost:8080/deletebyid?shoename=1

I mentioned the value 1 for id but it is assigning for shoename.

pretty much confused here. Please help me to understand how to perform delete operation.

Comment: why not `deletebyid?id=1` ?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand, can you help to elaborate please.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/deletebyid?id=1` - does that work?  Again, you should be POSTING for forms, but the key point is that you are posting/Getting the Shoename not the id.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/deletebyid?id=1  this is working! how can I perform this? how can i direct it to id instead of shoename? (i will use post method)

Comment: what data do you think that your form is posting? hint: `<input type="text" name="shoename">`

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks you so much for constantly answering my questions. I found the mistake myself that the attribute name was wrong. A silly mistake! I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own. I made a sily mistake in the JSP where earlier the JSP was:

```
   <h3>To delete an Item:</h3>
    <form action="deletebyid" method="get">
        Enter Shoe name: <input type="text" name="shoename"><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

the name attribute has to be Id!!! My mistake.

```
   <h3>To delete an Item:</h3>
    <form action="deletebyid" method="get">
        Enter Id: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

now it is working fine.